# How do I connect to multiple Exchange servers?

Tags: exchange-server

I'm working at a client site, and connect to their Exchange 2000 server via web mail.  I have Outlook 2007 running as well connected to my companies Exchange 2007 over HTTP.

Is there any way to connect to the client's Exchange 2000 server using anything other than web mail?  Ideally, Outlook 2007 would be able to do it, but I don't think that is possible.  POP isn't an option, because I need calendaring.

Thanks,

Zach

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, Outlook 2007 can only connect to one Exchange server per profile. To get this capability, you can upgrade to Outlook 2010. Outlook 2010 will connect to multiple Exchange servers in a single profile with no problem.

As a consultant, I have the need to connect to multiple email accounts all the time--my current profile is configured to connect to my corporate Exchange server, a client's Exchange server, two different Office 365 (Exchange Online) accounts, two different Google Apps accounts, and a Hotmail account. I love being able to easily navigate among all the different email accounts I regularly use via the native Outlook 2010 UI; I could never go back to multiple browser windows and Outlook profiles!

*[I realize this is a 'stale' question, but I noticed it popped up in a search on the topic so I'm posting this answer as this information isn't reflected in any of the earlier answers.]*

Answer (score 1):

You can always use more than one Outlook profile.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/HA011471581033.aspx

Comment: As far as I know you can't. Only in case the mailboxes are in the same organization you could use delegates (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291626) to have more than a Exchange mailbox open in the same Outlook window, but I understand that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way of opening 2 Outlook instances running 2 different profiles.

Please see this link -> http://www.pcauthority.com.au/Feature/136036,server-101-access-multiple-exchange-servers-with-outlook.aspx

Comment: I'd be careful using this method - I tried it a while back with Outlook 2007 and found data was getting mixed up between the two accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think outlook will allow more than 1 exchange server connection. One option would be using another email clients like thunderbird to connect to the other exchange server [I haven't tried it though]. In case you need to know how to configure thnderbird to connect to exchange server, here is a [link](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2007/03/30/howto-thunderbird-and-ms-exchange-server/).

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple profiles in Outlook. You won't be able to open them all at the same time, but you can set outlook to ask you whihc profile to open when you start it.

this is an old link, but the process is essentially the same if dealing with 2003 or 2007.
http://www.cod.edu/it/howdoi/profiles/

hth...

andres

Answer (score 0):

With Exchange 2000, external access is only possible using Outlook Web Access or POP/IMAP. With Exchange 2003 and 2007 you can connect using the outlook client using RPC, but not in 2000.
On a side, you can only have 1 Exchange connection in outlook, so you would have to use multiple profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's Mail Client will connect to any number of Exchange servers at a time. I believe that the Open Source Evolution mail client will similarly do so.